# Node_redis - how to remove a key?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

Is there any way to remove/delete an entry by key, using [Node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis)?  I can't see any such option from the docs..

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Here you can see what redis commands are work in this library [node_redis github](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/tree/master/test/commands)

As you can see "del" command is in the list.

And this command allow you delete keys from selected db as Jonatan answered.

Comment: @Elephant hdel is not there but it works. The reference should be https://redis.io/commands since "It supports all Redis commands" (quoted from github https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis).

Comment: @Elephant nevermind, i was looking at ioredis https://github.com/luin/ioredis/blob/master/lib/command.js

Comment: The link provided is now 404ing on github.com.

Answer (score 139):

You can `del` use like this:

```
redis.del('SampleKey');
```

Comment: This is the actual answer, giving a link to the redis docs was not an answer, the question was tagged with `node-redis`

Answer (score 23):

As everyone above has stated you can use del function. You can assure the successful delete operation using this syntax.

```
client.del('dummyvalue', function(err, response) {
   if (response == 1) {
      console.log("Deleted Successfully!")
   } else{
    console.log("Cannot delete")
   }
})
```

Because the DEL command will return `(integer) 1` in successful operation.

```
    redis 127.0.0.1:6379> DEL key 
    Success: (integer) 1
    Unsuccess: (integer) 0
```

Answer (score 13):

If I remember things correctly, `del` should do it.

Answer (score 9):

Hope this will help you

```
let redis = require("redis");

var redisclient = redis.createClient({
  host: "localhost",
  port: 6379
});

redisclient.on("connect", function () {
  console.log("Redis Connected");
});

redisclient.on('ready', function () {
  console.log("Redis Ready");
});

redisclient.set("framework", "AngularJS", function (err, reply) {
  console.log("Redis Set" , reply);
});

redisclient.get("framework", function (err, reply) {
  console.log("Redis Get", reply);
});

redisclient.del("framework",function (err, reply) {
  console.log("Redis Del", reply);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we want to delete `key="randomkey"`:

```js
redisClient.del(key, function(err, reply) {
  if (err)
    throw err;

  console.log("deleteRedisKey",reply)
  resolve(reply);
});
```

Answer (score -10):

Using sailsJs you can do this :

```
let id_todel = "5b845f9ea7f954bb732fdc52";
await sails.getDatastore('redis').leaseConnection(function during(db, proceed) {
      db.del(id_todel );
      return proceed(undefined, undefined);
});
```

Comment: This is specific to `sails`